# How do I send a PUT/DELETE request in HTML?

Tags: html, forms, rest

I'm making a REST API in PHP and I understand that I can capture the request method via `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']`.

However, how do I trigger PUT/DELETE requests in the browser?

I can't imagine changing the method attribute of the form tag to specify a method other than GET or POST would work on all browsers...plus the HTML standard doesn't recognize it.

Thanks.

Comment: When you say "in PHP" that implies you want to do the request server-side, and that's how I've answered. Your later statements about browsers and HTML imply that you want to do this from the client side, however... Can you clarify this?

Comment: Actually I should not have mentioned PHP at all.
I just want my client, be it a web browser or what have you, use HTML to transmit the data via HTTP as PUT or DELETE instead of only GET AND POST.

Comment: That kind-of changes the entire question.....  So your "php tag" is missleading to and will likely limit your audience.  You may want to re-post and be a bit more descriptive of what you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 6):

Usually this is done by a hidden form field, and handled in the application (not the webserver, by and large).

```
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="put" />
```

So in this case you'd use a simple set of if-else statements to determine if the `_method` variable is overridden (validly, of course). I'd use something like:

```
$method = 'get';
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
  if(isset($_POST['_method']
     && ($_POST['_method'] == 'PUT' || $_POST['_method'] == 'DELETE')) {
    $method = strtolower($_POST['_method']);
  } else {
    $method = 'post';
  }
}
```

This would be a simple way to determine the request type for your application or framework.

Comment: That's what I came up with too...the way Rails does it. But that heavily relies on convention. If someone editing the template does not add that, REST would not work.

But that seems like the only solution I could find too.
Say it isn't so :)

Comment: No, no! Put this kind of code into the *framework* and make it accessible to the code: this way the view doesn't do a thing, and the method is already determined.

Answer (score 1):

`fopen` will do HTTP, but I believe it will only do GET requests.  If you use `fsockopen`, you'll need to handle the HTTP protocol yourself, generating headers, etc..

You can use [HTTPRequest](http://php.net/manual/en/function.httprequest-send.php) (in the `php_http` extension) or [PEAR](http://tinyurl.com/6vb5mt).

Update:

If you're really talking about making PUT/DELETE requests *to* your PHP scripts, rather than *from* them, this question may be of interest:

[Are the PUT, DELETE, HEAD, etc methods available in most web browsers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165779)

Comment: I was actually looking at HTTPRequest.

I'm trying to imagine how I would implement PUT.
I would have an HTML form with the data already present in the fields.
On submit, I don't understand how I can trigger PUT so that my form handler handles this as PUT.

Could you shed some light on this please?

Thanks.

Comment: @Housni Assuming the browser supports PUT implies it has the capability for the HTML/JS to specify exactly what is in the body of that PUT request.  For now, the best you can do in a portable way is to do a POST.  If you use `method="PUT"` I suspect the browser will probably treat the request exactly as POST, meaning that the form fields will be "multipart/form-data" encoded, so the body of the PUT will be "field1=value&field1=value&...".  I believe you can use PUT/DELETE with arbitrary data via a JavaScript `XMLHTTPRequest`, though I have not tried it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use PHP's built-in functions, but not cURL, you're pretty much stuck with fsockopen(), etc.,

or at best, a library built around those functions, like [Snoopy](http://sourceforge.net/projects/snoopy/)

Answer (score -1):

You may want to take a look at WebDav ([PHP WebDav slide show](http://talks.php.net/show/webdav/)). It's built to PUSH, DELETE, Etc...  Of course the server you are targeting needs to accept PUSH's and DELETE's which would mean Apache is using mod_webdav or something similar.  Otherwise a lower-level solution will be required (as others have indicated)