# How does Backbone send a PUT and PATH request to server

Tags: http, backbone.js

Regarding [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1835711/how-do-i-send-a-put-delete-request-in-html) question and also many documents have stated that sending a PUT request directly via form in browser is impossible due to security reason.

However, What I am seeing in Backbone is that it could still send a direct PUT request via browser without a workaround like adding a hidden form field.

And they're confusing to me. Is there anything that I'm missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A form can only send a GET or a POST request, as [set in the `method` attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/Form#attr-method).

However, Backbone [delegates its requests](http://backbonejs.org/#Sync) to [`jQuery.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) by default (or whatever you want via [`Backbone.ajax`](http://backbonejs.org/#Sync-ajax)) which itself wraps [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest), an [object that can send PUT/DELETE/PATCH requests](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest#Parameters).

From https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest

> XMLHttpRequest is a JavaScript object that was designed by Microsoft
>   and adopted by Mozilla, Apple, and Google. It's now being standardized
>   in the W3C. It provides an easy way to retrieve data from a URL
>   without having to do a full page refresh. A Web page can update just a
>   part of the page without disrupting what the user is doing. 
>   XMLHttpRequest is used heavily in AJAX programming.

Answer (score 1):

> many documents have stated that sending a PUT request directly via browser is impossible due to security reason

Citation please.

Backbone sends a PUT just like it sends any other request, with jQuery,

```
Backbone.ajax({
  type: 'PUT'
  ...
});
```

It is just some server side langauges,like PHP, that have problems with receiving a PUT request.

The hidden form field is used when posting from a `<form>`. Backbone uses javascript.